# changing list properties (back color, underling, text size etc)

Tags: c#, asp.net, listboxitem

I'm trying to change the text properties within a list box when the list item is checked. Currently if i check an item it will print a message in the label so at least its registering a selection. Any ideas on how i can change the text properties i.e. if an item is selected then change the color of the text on the selected item from default black to red?

```
for (int i = 0; i < checklist.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (checkist.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            lbltest.Text = "yayee";
            //checklist.Items[i].Attributes.CssStyle(); maybee ??
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `CheckboxList.Items` is a collection of `ListItems` I think your best bet is to use `CssStyle` to add individual style attributes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < checklist.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (checkist.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        checklist.Items[i].Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "red");         
    }
}
```

Any other modifications, such as underline or bold could be made in a similar fashion.  You just have to use standard CSS:

```
// Bold
checklist.Items[i].Attributes.CssStyle.Add("font-weight", "bold");  

// Underline
checklist.Items[i].Attributes.CssStyle.Add("text-decoration", "underline");
```

Comment: the documentation shows that the checklist property can be changed for the whole list - checklist.Font....; But it doesn't allow individual items to be changed  for example checklist.items[i].font...

Comment: @ArvidBoome I'm not sure I understand.  What exactly is wrong with the example I posted to change text color?

Comment: sorry i tried that it says...System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem does not contain a definition for 'ForeColor'

Comment: @ArvidBoome Ahh, I understand now.  That's my mistake to make the assumption that `Items` was a collection of `Checkbox`.  I will look for an updated solution

Comment: Any ideas if the font properties could be changed like this. e.g. if i wanted to underline it or highlight it bold?

Comment: Updated with additional examples.  Beyond that, study up on CSS.  Also, if you found the answer to be of decent quality an upvote would also be nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

The easier and faster way to do that is on client side with java script, you can use a simple jQuery function for that.

```
$("#checklistId > checkbox").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
         //Add the style
    }
    else {
        //Add the unchecked style
    }
});
```